# Addition to NSMutableArray() during NSURL session not recognized after session

Tags: ios, scope, swift2

I am using NSURL to get the source code of a website page. I am passing MySQL query instructions via the URL to interact with the database to get a list of a user's friends. Everything works well up to the point of adding the returned data to an array, to them be filed into a table view. The website's response prints to the terminal well, however if I add it to the array to be added to the table view, it is not recognized after the NSURl session is complete.

Code:

```
//
//  viewFriendsViewController.swift
//  collaboration
//
//  Created by nick on 11/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Supreme Leader. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class viewFriendsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var textArray: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection Section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.textArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.textArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
        return cell
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let username = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("username")
        if username != nil {
            let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.casacorazon.org/ios.html")
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                    }
                    self.textArray.addObject(responseString as! String)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        } else {
            self.textArray.addObject("Error")
            self.textArray.addObject("You are not logged in")
        }
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You have to reload the table view data. Add

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

right after

```
self.textArray.addObject(responseString as! String)
```

---

I recommend to declare `textArray` as non-optional Swift Array

```
var textArray = [String]()
```

then all occurrences of `addObject` have to replaced with `append`
and change the line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the value for index path to

```
cell.textLabel?.text = self.textArray[indexPath.row] // no type casting needed
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Once I get 15 reputation I will upvote you